# MySQL Query, multiple counts and sums

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query that outputs to a php table but I'm having issues in joining two tables that both use a COUNT:

```
$query = "SELECT mqe.registration, 
        COUNT(*) AS numberofenqs,
        COUNT(DISTINCT ucv.ip) AS unique_views,
        SUM(ucv.views) AS total_views
        FROM main_quick_enquiries AS mqe
        LEFT OUTER JOIN used_car_views AS ucv
        ON ucv.numberplate = mqe.registration
        WHERE mqe.registration IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY mqe.registration ORDER BY numberofenqs DESC";
```

The query runs, but the number within the numberofenqs column is always wrong as i know from performing that query on its own that it comes in with the correct result:

```
SELECT registration, COUNT(*) AS numberofenqs FROM main_quick_enquiries GROUP BY registration ORDER BY numberofenqs DESC
```

Why is the COUNT(*) not working correctly in top query code and where is it getting the figures from?

Comment: Can you show some sample records from both on what is wrong / different?  Are you getting a Cartesian result as a result of your lef-join to used_car_views that might have multiple same registration values?  Don't know, just considering.

Comment: Try counting something else

Answer (score 1):

it could be because of LEFT OUTER JOIN ...

Try to run this:

```
SELECT registration
, count(*)
FROM main_quick_enquiries
GROUP BY registration
```

and compare it with this result

```
SELECT mqe.registration
, count(*)
FROM main_quick_enquiries mqe
LEFT OUTER JOIN used_car_views ucv
ON ucv.numberplate = mqe.registration
GROUP BY mqe.registration
```

There could be a problem :) in duplicity rows... try to find one specific registration number, and compare the details of both query

```
SELECT *
FROM main_quick_enquiries
WHERE registration = XXXX
```

+

```
SELECT *
FROM main_quick_enquiries mqe
LEFT OUTER JOIN used_car_views ucv
ON ucv.numberplate = mqe.registration
WHERE registration = XXXX
```

you should see the diffs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All, but I think I've nailed it with COUNT(DISTINCT mqe.id) instead of COUNT(*).